# Change in x axis display

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, x-axis

I have a table with an index representing the trading days for each year, as if they were business days. In my chart, I need the x-axis to display the corresponding months of these days rather than the day numbers. For example, January (index 0 to 22), ... etc. I have a calendar table related to my database, but it didn't work for me. Can someone help?

columns in order (product, quotes, index, date)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKmos.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gY15.png)

I tried everthing i know. And i need the x axis displayng the months without agregate the quotes in a sum.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6N3D.png)

i want this, with the x axis below (month names):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGXmA.png)

Comment: First, what does "didn't work for me" mean?
Second, do you have a calendar table?

Answer (score 0):

A quick 'hack' would be to hide the X-axis values, and overlay text boxes for the Months on top.

[image]

If you want a tooltip to show day month (as shown above in the image) then you can create a new date column for all being in the same year. For example:

Create a new Calculated Column on your table with:

```
Chart Date = DATE( 2000, MONTH([Date]), DAY([Date]) )
```

Then ensure this column is set to Date type `Date` with Format `(d mmmm)`.

[image]

Use this new column for your X-axis. Then same as mentioned above, hide the values and overlay the month text boxes.